# Pd merge specific column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, vlookup

can u help me, how to do vlookup or pd merge on speccific column in the blank excel column. I just know how to do pd merge and the value come as a new column

I have a dataframe `df1`

```
  index id  Value   Info        
0   0   A1          xxx 
1   1   A2          xxx 
2   2   A3          xxx 
3   3   A4          xxx
```

and also this data frame `df2`

```
  index id  Value           
0   0   A1  Apple       
1   1   A2  Orange      
2   2   A3  Banana      
3   3   A4  Grape
```

I wish to get to the following outcome when merging `df1` and `df2`

```
  index id  Value   Info        
0   0   A1  Apple   xxx 
1   1   A2  Orange  xxx 
2   2   A3  Banana  xxx 
3   3   A4  Grape   xxx
```

Comment: What are the keys that you want to merge on?

Comment: value key refers on id

Answer (score 0):

This could be straight forward considering pandas operations.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"index":[0,1,2,3],"id":["A1","A2","A3","A4"],"Info":['xx1','xx2','xx3','xx4']})
df1

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"index":[0,1,2,3],"id":["A1","A2","A3","A4"],"Value":['Apple','Orange','Banana','Grape']})
df2
```

You could use:

```
df1.merge(df2)
```

which gives the below output:

```
index   id  Info    Value
0   0   A1  xx1     Apple
1   1   A2  xx2     Orange
2   2   A3  xx3     Banana
3   3   A4  xx4     Grape
```

Comment: thanks this is help full, but can we do it on the same column ?. so the table position on my excel file is not change or adding new column.